# How to plot horizontal lines ('hlines') on open / close?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I have just started working with pine-script and run into my first issue whilst working on an indicator that plots supply/demand zones. Because close and open are series types I cannot use them within the hline function due to the following error -

*line 19: Cannot call 'hline' with argument 'price'='call 'operator SQBR' (series float)'. An argument of 'series float' type was used but a 'input float' is expected*

Is there a work around to convert series types into input types or an alternative function that can be used with series types to plot the hlines?

```
indicator("My script")

if close > open 
    onePercentClose  = close / 100
    diff = close - open
    if diff > onePercentClose
        hline(close[1])
        hline(open[1])
```

Answer (score 2):

No, `hline()` cannot create lines based on series values. The value must be known at compile time. If you want to plot horizontal lines, you can use either the regular `plot()` function to draw plots or the `line.new()` function to draw line objects.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

float h = na
if close > open 
    onePercentClose  = close / 100
    diff = close - open
    if diff > onePercentClose
        h := close[1]
        l = line.new(bar_index[1], open[1], bar_index, open[1])
        
plot(h, style = plot.style_linebr)
```